# Solutions of a specific Riccati equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In SUSY literature potential $V(x)$ is given in terms of superpotential $W(x)$ as $V=W^2-W'$. I was trying to reverse this relation for Morse potential which is $V_m=D_e(1-e^{-\alpha x})^2$ where $D_e$ and $\alpha$ are constants. Since it is a Riccati equation I went on Wikipedia and used method given there to transform it to a second order linear equation. In the notation used there general Riccati equation reads:

$y'=q_0(x)+q_1(x)y+q_2(x)y^2$

and in my case $y=W(x)$, $\,\,q_0(x)=-V(x)$, $\,\,q_2(x)=1$ and $q_1(x)=0$. According to Wikipedia it can be rewritten as

$u''-R(x)u'+S(x)u=0$

with $y=\frac{-u'}{uq_2}=\frac{-u'}{u}$ $R=q_1+\frac{q_2'}{q_2}=0+\frac{1'}{1}=0$ and $S=q_2q_0=-V(x)$. Then it takes the form

$u''-V(x)u=0$

and plugging in $V_m(x)$ for $V(x)$ it becomes

$u''-D_e(1-e^{-\alpha x})^2u=0$.

Solving for $u$ can give $y$ as defined above. I unfortunately didn't success in solving it. Is it possible to find an analytical solution? Maybe there is another way to reverse this relation (express $W$ in terms of $V$)?

Answer (score 0):

$$y''-D(1-e^{-\alpha{x}})^{2}y=0$$
Let
$$e^{-\alpha{x}}=z$$
than
$$\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}=\alpha^{2}{z}\frac{d}{dz}+\alpha^{2}{z^{2}}\frac{d^{2}}{dz^{2}}$$
Also let $D/\alpha^{2}=k$, then
$$z^{2}y''+zy'-k(1-z)^{2}y=0$$
Now, let $\xi=2\sqrt{z}$ and let
$$y(z)=e^{\sqrt{k}(\ln(z)-z)}\eta(\xi)$$
One obtains
$$\xi\eta''+(2\sqrt{k}+1-\xi)\eta'-\frac{1}{2}\eta=0$$
Which is a confluent hypergeometric differential equation http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html The solution is
$$\eta(\xi)=a_{1}F_{1}(1/2, 2\sqrt{k}+1, \xi)+bU(1/2, 2\sqrt{k}+1, \xi)$$
If you want to know about the properties of this function watch Abramowitz and Stegun, there is a whole chapter there full of useful relations.